# some libraries files in /lib have 0 size "empty"

Tags: fedora, libraries, ldconfig

during an update dnf throw this

> ldconfig: File /lib/librav1e.so.0 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/librav1e.so.0.6.6 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libnl-3.so.200 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libnl-3.so.200.26.0 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libnl-genl-3.so.200 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libnl-genl-3.so.200.26.0 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libnl-idiag-3.so.200 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libnl-idiag-3.so.200.26.0 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libnl-nf-3.so.200 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libnl-nf-3.so.200.26.0 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libnl-route-3.so.200 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libnl-route-3.so.200.26.0 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libnl-xfrm-3.so.200 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libnl-xfrm-3.so.200.26.0 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libSvtAv1Dec.so.0 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libSvtAv1Dec.so.0.8.7 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libSvtAv1Enc.so.1 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libSvtAv1Enc.so.1.4.1 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libnn.so.2 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libnn.so.2.0.0 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libodbc.so.2 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libodbc.so.2.0.0 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libodbccr.so.2 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libodbccr.so.2.0.0 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libodbcinst.so.2 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libodbcinst.so.2.0.0 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libtemplate.so.2 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libtemplate.so.2.0.0 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/liborc-0.4.so.0 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/liborc-0.4.so.0.33.0 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/liborc-test-0.4.so.0 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/liborc-test-0.4.so.0.33.0 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libOpenCL.so.1 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libOpenCL.so.1.0.0 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libnss_mdns.so.2 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libnss_mdns4.so.2 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libnss_mdns6.so.2 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libnss_mdns6_minimal.so.2 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libnss_mdns_minimal.so.2 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/liblockdev.so.1 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/liblockdev.so.1.0.0 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libhwy.so.1 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libhwy.so.1.0.7 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libhwy_contrib.so.1 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libhwy_contrib.so.1.0.7 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libhwy_test.so.1 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libhwy_test.so.1.0.7 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libgd.so.3 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libgd.so.3.0.11 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libsane.so.1 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libsane.so.1.2.1 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libgraphene-1.0.so.0 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libgraphene-1.0.so.0.1000.6 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libcdda_interface.so.0 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libcdda_interface.so.0.10.2 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libcdda_paranoia.so.0.10.2 is empty, not checked.
> ldconfig: File /lib/libcdda_paranoia.so.0 is empty, not checked.

what could cause this and how can I fix it ?
I tried to force reinstall some of the packages but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the disk became 100% full when those libraries were being installed/updated?

If you made a large update, then `dnf clean packages`, then reinstalling those library packages one by one might be a way to fix it.